# Given a number $n$, what is the minimal number of operations $+1, -1, /2, /3$ required to reach $0$?

Tags: algorithms, arithmetic

Given a number $n > 0$, what is the minimal number of operations to reduce this number to $0$ ?

We can use these operations:

- $+1$
- $-1$
- $/2$ (when number is divisible by $2$)
- $/3$ (when number is divisible by $3$)

It would be awesome if you would also provide a proof.

Comment: How about a hint: "Homework"

Comment: @YashJain This only has one right answer

Comment: @TheGreatDuck What else is the appropiate reaction to a 0 effort cheating try?

Comment: @TheGreatDuck I think you're on to something. Now we just need a hacker to trace his IP and a law suit to locate the users address based on it. I'll start by baking some cookies

Comment: The number decreases the most when divided by $3$. If we cannot divide by $3$ that means that it leaves remainder $+1$ or $2\equiv -1$ mod $3$. Therefore, we only need to expend one of the operations $\pm1$ to get a multiple of $3$. And continue dividing by $3$. Therefore, to know the number of steps we expand $n$ in base $3$: $n=a_0+a_13+...+a_k3^k$, with $a_i=1\text{ or }2$. When ever a digit is non-zero we need to use one operation $\pm1$. When there is a $0$ digit we use a $/3$. We reach $0$ in about $log_3(n)$, the length of the base-3 expansion.

Comment: @Sudix Why do you think this is "homework" ? I found this problem and I am trying to solve it. I have some basic idea but can not prove if it is right or wrong.

Comment: @Orole it will be logarithmic for sure but I am trying to find algorithm for minimal required number of required steps.

Comment: @Druudik Expanded the comment with the algorithm.

Comment: @Druudik Because you don't display the effort of somebody who found an exciting problem and is now trying to gnaw away at it till the mystery box breaks and you end up with a result. E.g. you'd given us your approach from the start, hoping to get some input on whether it's correct or not, and you'd most certainly would have offered us a (failed) induction as well.

Comment: @Sudix the OP is fairly new. I am sure he/she is still growing used to the mathjax. It came easy to me, but perhaps he/she (the name doesn’t suggest a gender) is still getting used to it. The OP also explained that it is not homework so now move on, but if you still don’t have faith in the fact that the OP’s question really isn’t homework, then perhaps we should ask him/her where he/she found the question.

Comment: Where have you found the question and what have you attempted thus far?

Comment: @TheGreatDuck but what if the OP doesn’t? We don’t know if the OP will plagiarise the original source as much as how we don’t know if the OP will *not* plagiarise the original source and be honest with us. I’m not trying to be the Good Samaritan or anything, but I genuinely believe the OP.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck ok I agree with you there...

Comment: Guys I showed my effort but I deleted that comment, I had an idea it is not that hard, my general idea was to create table and start filling it from the bottom. Then calculate each next step from the previous ones based on modularity with 3 ( it would be either 1+ F(n/3), 2+F((n+1)/3), 1+F((n-1)/3) etc. and get minimum of those). It was a bit complex for me to describe that thought, that is why I did not. I am new here, so excuse my brevity - just wanted a quick answer. And about that link, it is private webpage where you must have access so I can not give you a link.

Comment: What do you mean by number -- integer, rational, real or complex or what?

Comment: Edited ( n>0 ).

Comment: @TheGreatDuck I'd say give the OP more of a chance, after all that's their first question after having just joined. `that isnt good enough` It *is* good enough to infer that $\,n\,$ is a positive integer (though, in fact, allowing negative integers wouldn't change the question). If anything, I don't  understand Allawonder's comment, since it's quite obvious that $\,n\,$ must be an integer, otherwise no finite sequence of operations will ever get it to $\,0\,$.

Answer (score 0):

If the answer is $f(n)$, then $f(n)=1+\min(f(n-1),f(n+1),f(n/2),f(n/3))$.

Try using induction and see if you can find a pattern. For example the first few are $f(0)=0,f(1)=1,f(2)=2,f(3)=2$.

It might be hard to find a nice general solution though because I think this problem has connections to Catalan's conjecture and ABC conjecture.

Comment: You have a cycle - how can you calculate f(n+1) when you need to know the answer for f(n-1) and for f(n-1) you need to know answer for f(n+1) ?

Comment: The first line doesn't mean that @Akababa is giving you an *algorithm* to compute $f$. It is true by pure logic and that's all.

Comment: Yeah you're right - when I tried it I basically assumed you would always divide by 2 if you could. It may be possible to prove that you never need to add 1.

Comment: Adding $1$ can certainly be beneficial — starting at $127$ for example.

Answer (score 0):

*This is not a solution but an extended comment.*

Here is a quite tempting algorithm:

- if $n$ is divisible by $3$, divide it by $3$. Otherwise :

  $\qquad\bullet$ if $n$ is divisible by $2$ then divide it by $2$. Otherwise :

  $\qquad \qquad \bullet$ $n$ is either $6k+1$ (in which case subtract $1$) or $6k-1$ (in which case add $1$).

Iterate.

Comment: Just to give a concrete example, this algorithm gives the wrong answer for $3^n+1$.

Comment: That's right! Maybe we should be looking for the "closest" power of $3$ in terms of this graph distance.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck I was not asking for clarification, simply showing a greedy algorithm in a better display than the comments section would allow for.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck a link to what?

Comment: @TheGreatDuck there are exceptions to every rule, and I believe this is one.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck the reviewers do not seem to have all the same opinion re. this, see comments above. Moreover,  when I have more to say about this problem, I wouldn't like to have to re-write everything.